# After reset /etc/hosts, firefox stuck requiring authentication

Tags: linux, firefox, hosts-file

I have a test site, which need authentication to access. The map between ip and domain is given in /etc/hosts.
Today, the ip of the domain changed, so I modifid /etc/hosts. Then the bad thing happens, the authentication window can't be closed no matter I input the corrent password or close the window by click 'cancel' button or the close button. And I have to kill firefox by 'pkill firefox'.
I have a virtual machine running windows xp, and after modifying hosts file, I can access the site successfully.
I have try to reboot the operating system and clear the history record of firfox. But they don't work.
My system is redhat5.4 and firfox is 3.0.12.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to explain, but after clicking the 'cancel' button a lot of times, the authentication window didn't appear any more and the visiting is normal now.